# Distinguish between number and length

Tags: numbering, tex-core, latex3, dimensions

In my job, I need a macro to distinguish between `number` and `length`. Length here means, for example:

(1) `\textwidth`, `\parindent`, etc

(2) `\newdimen\mylena  \mylena=10cm`

(3) `\def\mylenb{2in}`

(4) `5.2in`

I want the macro to work like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\newdimen\mylena  \mylena=10cm
\def\mylenb{2in}
\def\mynum{5.2}

\newcommand{\numorlen}[1]{
  % if #1 is a number, do something, here, to be simple, just typeset "It's a number".
  % if #1 is a length, do something, here, to be simple, just typeset "It's a length".
}

\numorlen{\textwidth} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{\mylena} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{\mylenb} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{5.2in} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{5.2} % typeset It's a number
\numorlen{\mynum} % typeset It's a number

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cheap way to do this. It doesn't actually check to see if the input is a number or a length, only whether its rightmost character of the expanded argument is an integer. Assuming the only possibilities are numbers and lengths, it works. However, `\numorlen{m2}` would incorrectly be identified as a number. Similarly, `\numorlen{2m}` would incorrectly be identified as a length.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newdimen\mylena  \mylena=10cm
\def\mylenb{2in}
\def\mynum{5.2}

\newcommand{\numorlen}[1]{\StrRight{#1}{1}[\lastchr]\IfInteger{\lastchr}{It's a number}{It's a length}}

\begin{document}

\numorlen{\textwidth} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{\mylena} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{\mylenb} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{5.2in} % typeset It's a length
\numorlen{5.2} % typeset It's a number
\numorlen{\mynum} % typeset It's a number

\end{document}
```